# How to display images using Javascript and JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have to display images to the browser and I want to get the image from a JSON response and display it to the browser using Javascript. This is what the JSON response looks like:

```
[{
    "0":"101",
    "member_id":"101",
    "1":"3k.png",
    "image_nm":"3k.png",
    "2":"\/images\/phones\/",
    "image_path":"\/images\/"
},{
    "0":"102",
    "member_id":"102",
    "1":"mirchi.png",
    "image_nm":"mirchi.png",
    "2":"images\/phones\/",
    "image_path":"images\/phones\/"
},{
    "0":"103",
    "member_id":"103",
    "1":"masti.png",
    "image_nm":"masti.png",
    "2":"images\/phones\/",
    "image_path":"images\/phones\/"
}]
```

How do I do this (I am a beginner)?

here is the code what i wrote...

```
       var jsonString =   '[{"0":"101","member_id":"101","1":"3k.png","image_nm":"3k.png","2":"\/images\/phones\/","image_path":"\/images\/phones\/"},{"0":"102","member_id":"102","1":"mirchi.png","image_nm":"mirchi.png","2":"images\/phones\/","image_path":"images\/phones\/"},{"0":"103","member_id":"103","1":"masti.png","image_nm":"masti.png","2":"images\/phones\/","image_path":"images\/phones\/"}]';
       var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);

       for(var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++){
       var img = new Image();
       img.setAttribute("src",obj[i][2] + obj[i][1]);
       document.body.appendChild(img);
         }
```

Comment: And what concrete output do you expect in your example?

Comment: i ecpect all images should display on the browser

Comment: of course, but please add an exact html code result which do you expect from the code sample you pasted here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you parsed your json in a variable called `json`, this would add all images in a container with id `yourcontainer`:

```
var images = '';
for( var i=0, max<json.length; ++i ) {
  images += '<img src="' + json[i]['image_path'] + json[i]['image_nm'] + '" />';
}

document.getElementById( 'yourcontainer' ).innerHTML = images;
```

Comment: var jsonString =         '[{"0":"101","member_id":"101","1":"3k.png","image_nm":"3k.png","2":"\/images\/phones\/","image_path":"\/images\/phones\/"},{"0":"102","member_id":"102","1":"mirchi.png","image_nm":"mirchi.png","2":"images\/phones\/","image_path":"images\/phones\/"},{"0":"103","member_id":"103","1":"masti.png","image_nm":"masti.png","2":"images\/phones\/","image_path":"images\/phones\/"}]';
                 var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);

Comment: yeah i replaced and i wrote the code like this but images are not displayed on the browser..for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++){
    var img = new Image();
    img.setAttribute("src",obj[i][2] + obj[i][1]);
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}

Comment: you would have to paste your whole code (maybe using [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) ), so i can see, what's wrong. possibly you have no container div?

Comment: @krishnabhargavi I put your code at http://jsfiddle.net/KdMwe/ and it works, when replacing your image urls, with something other. So I think you should double-check your image paths to make sure the images are actually where your page searches for them.

Comment: the path of the images is correct..the images of the phones displayed on the browser???

Comment: @krishnabhargavi your image paths are inconsistent in the example give. in the first entry, e.g., the properties `2` and `image_path` show different entries. is this example online somewhere?

Comment: yeah thank you i didnt observed the code yet..but why the paths are different??what i have to do now?

Comment: @krishnabhargavi you didn't give us the code that created the json up to now ,-)

Comment: i created the json using thid code:  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
  echo json_encode($result);
  echo"</script>";

Comment: @krishnabhargavi and where does `$result` come from? I doubt that there's an error in PHP's `json_encode` function. Maybe you should open a separate question for this problem after all.

Comment: if you ask about the result then my code is very long...jst i need the images onthe browser

Comment: @krishnabhargavi I think we narrowed your problem down to some wrong image paths provided by the json. Any further help you need should be in a new question possibly in a new question, providing at least parts of the code that lead to `$result`. I'll stop commenting here now, as stackoverflow would like to move this to chat already ,-)

Comment: hey last question tell me..in your code what is yourcontainer variable??

Comment: That was just any container (like a `div`) with an `id` of "yourcontainer". The purpose was to let you control, where your images appear on the page and you replaced it by `document.body.appendChild(img);`

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty straight forward. If this is json_encoded, then we can use json[key] to get the value, if you aren't familiar with the term 'key', json encodes arrays in the key:value, format, so for this, if we used json[member_id], we would get '101', if we used json[image_nm], we would get '3k.png', putting this all together it seems as if it's pretty well separated, you just have to know what goes where. I have an idea, but not 100%,I would expect you to do something like

```
var myImages = '';
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
  myImages += '<img src="'+json[i]['image_path']+json[i]['img_nm']+'" />';
}
document.getElementById('myImgHolder').innerHTML = myImages;
```

Based on your json data, this would evaluate a variable and test it against the length of the json array. The statement also declares that while the variable is less than the total length of the json array, we will iterate to the next object. We would expect output along the format of -

```
<img src="/images/3k.png" />.
```

Then it would take the new images and place them in a Div with the id of myImgHolder.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT 1**

If you don't have a container to place these images inside of it, then you will need to create the container and place it somewhere.

```
var myImgHolder = document.createElement('div');
myImgHolder.setAttribute("id", "myImgHolder");
document.getElementById('ICanTargetThis').appendChild(myImgHolder);
```

The above code sets the variable myImgHolder to the creation of a new DIV element. Then, using the variable, we declare the attribute "id" to set as 'myImgHolder'. Now we have the  element. But what do we do with it? Well we MUST target an existing element within our page, even if we're just targeting the  tag...something. then we use the .appendChild method and use our variable...appendChild(myImgHolder);

Comment: a <div id="myImgHolder"> where all the iamges that we have created are then placed into.

Comment: that is the html code...but i need to write all these stuff in javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery here.

Add following script in the head tag.

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var url = "entries.json";
$.getJSON(url, function (url){
 var img= "";
$.each(url, function () {
 img += '<li><img src= "' + this.images+ '"></li>';
});
$('body').append(img);
});
});
</script>
```