# Get all image links from content of the javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, simple-html-dom

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var productJsonMedias = 
    [
        {"thumb":"domain.com/a-1.jpg","zoom":"domain.com/b-1.jpg","description":"","altText":"Product Name"},   
        {"thumb":"domain.com/a-2.jpg","zoom":"domain.com/b-2.jpg","description":"","altText":"Product Name"}    
    ];
```

I want to get all image links from content of the json and this scipt is embed on web. I am using Simple Html Dom to crawl web.

Comment: what you've tried **YOURSELF** to get all images from content of the json?

Comment: Your json format is incorrect

Comment: @BeingSunny i get content from class or id, ex $html->find('.product-detail-title h1') but this case I don't know I must how to do

Comment: @MdRashedPervez I just updated the script

Comment: see this link- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597624/how-to-display-images-using-javascript-and-json

Comment: @MdRashedPervez I want to get this script from a web page. After that I use json decode to convert to array php... I am not an admin of this web.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get from JSON you should use AJAX:

```js
var data = [];
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open('GET', '*LINK TO JSON*', true);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;
     if (xhr.status != 200) {
      alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
     } else {
      try{         
        data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      }catch(e){
        alert("ERROR: " + e);
      }
    }
   }
```

If you want to get HTML code from the page you should use php or node.js (you should send GET request and parse the code).

Better send ajax GET request for JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regex to get the json:

```
$str = <<<EOF
<script type="text/javascript">
    var productJsonMedias = 
    [
        {"thumb":"domain.com/a-1.jpg","zoom":"domain.com/b-1.jpg","description":"","altText":"Product Name"},   
        {"thumb":"domain.com/a-2.jpg","zoom":"domain.com/b-2.jpg","description":"","altText":"Product Name"}    
    ];
</script>
EOF;

$html = str_get_html($str);
$script = $html->find('script', 0);
if(!preg_match('/\[.*\]/', $script, $m)) die('cant find json!');

print_r(json_decode($m[0], true));

/*
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [thumb] => domain.com/a-1.jpg
            [zoom] => domain.com/b-1.jpg
            [description] => 
            [altText] => Product Name
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [thumb] => domain.com/a-2.jpg
            [zoom] => domain.com/b-2.jpg
            [description] => 
            [altText] => Product Name
        )

)
*/
```